# How to build gperftools as a static library?

Tags: configure, autotools, gperftools

I read in the INSTALL file of gperftools that it can be built as a static library. How would I be able to do it?

From my understanding of static libraries: I need to configure it to make a .a file that will have .o files, instead of stubs to shared libraries. But I'm completely clueless as to what to pass to ./configure to get this behaviour. I can build my gperftools with ./configure --prefix=PATH_TO_SOME_LOCATION , and I get a neat little folder of .so files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this:

`./configure --disable-shared CXXFLAGS=-g && make`

It depends on several factors, including your platform, compiler and gperftools version.

You can refer to the documentation here:

- [gperftools README](http://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README)
- [gperftools INSTALL](http://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/INSTALL)